# How to schedule notifications in advance?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to create a function that recalls an event. 10min, 20min, 1 hours in advance.

How to do ?

```
-(void)programmer_un_rappel_sans_avance{

    NSDate *fireDate = [picker_date date];

    UILocalNotification *local_rappel_notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    local_rappel_notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    local_rappel_notification.alertBody = @"VOUS AVEZ  UN VOL MAINTENANT !!";
    local_rappel_notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    local_rappel_notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    local_rappel_notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication ]scheduleLocalNotification:local_rappel_notification];
}
```

Comment: Which ios version you are using??

Comment: I use IOS 10.2 SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all from **iOS 10** , apple has deprecated use of `UILocalNotifications` and they have introduced extremely amazing framework for rich notifications called `UserNotifications` framework. So I ill suggest you to use this framework instead of using deprecated one. [This](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios-10-day-by-day-day-5-user-notifications) post has explained use of this framework in a very simple way.Though the post describes `Swift` coding you can get the idea and convert same in `Objective-c` or you can also follow [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/) tutorial which explains same in both `swift` and `objective-c`.

There are several types of notification triggers which you can use:

1. **UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger** : Enables notification to be sent
   after the specified time interval. Can repeat the time interval if
   required.
2. **UNCalendarNotificationTrigger** : Notifies user using date components
   e.g. trigger at 8am. It can also be repeated.
3. **UNLocationNotificationTrigger** : Adds ability to trigger when the
   user enters or exits a particular location.

In your case you can use **UNCalendarNotificationTrigger**.

**EDIT:**
For your requirement do like this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateComponents *time = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:your_date];
components.hour = time.hour;
components.minute = time.minute - time_you_want_to_fire_notification_before; //ex. if you want to fire notification before 10 mins then -10 from time.minute
```

and to fire notification use this:

```
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
```

Comment: OK. I already use a picker date. So what do I need to add to my code to receive notification, 10min in advance ?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Pleasure brother. Happy Coding..!